Covariant derivative of a Riemann tensor
I'm trying to calculate the covariant derivative of a Riemann tensor, and I'm using the following way, but there is some problem in my calculations because my calculations do not match with the calculations mentioned in the research paper.
\begin{align}
    R_{ijkl} &= g_{im} R^{m}{}_{jkl}\tag1\\    
    \nabla^{a} R_{ijkl} &= g_{im} \nabla^{a}  R^{m}{}_{jkl}\tag2\\
    \nabla^{a} R_{ijkl} &= g_{im} g^{ab} \nabla_{b}  R^{m}{}_{jkl}\tag3
\end{align}
where $\nabla_{b} R^{m}_{jkl}$ I have defined as
\begin{equation}
    \nabla_{i}  R^{j}_{abc} = R^{j}_{abc,i} + \Gamma^{j}_{ik} R^{k}_{abc} 
                              - \Gamma^{m}_{ia} R^{j}_{mbc} 
                              - \Gamma^{m}_{ib} R^{j}_{amc} 
                              - \Gamma^{m}_{ic} R^{j}_{abm}
\end{equation}
Can anyone please help me in this regard? Where could be a problem? I'm sure that the definition of riemann= $R^{i}_{jkl}$ is the Riemann tensor.
Thank you.

Please look at this page https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/289491/what-are-some-mathematica-packages-used-for-general-relativity/289506#289506

We need to see this in mathJax and also what that research paper claims.

I have pasted code from the Mathematica notebook, but it is not formatting well in the post.

I said mathJax not mathematica notebook and what that research paper claims.

I would like to reproduce Eq. (27) using Eqs. (1&2), from the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/2306.11558. I'm sure that all my calculations are correct, except the terms F^{\mu} and F^{\mu \nu} in Eqs. (1) and (2), respectively.

I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with mathJax, but use LaTex. Should I type in Latex and share the picture here? Or if I share the picture of notes written by hand?

I did a small edit to show you how mathjax works. For someone with LaTex knowledge this should be doable I hope. Now to the math: before I struggle with a paper and (even less attractive) with your mathematica code: are you trying to verify equations (1),(2),(3)? They are standard for a metric compatible connection such as the Levi-Civita connection.

I don't know how Mathematica works, bit it seems to me like you tried to redo all the calculations by hand. Doesn't Mathematica have built in functions to calculate Riemann curvature tensors and covariant derivatives? why didn't you use them?

@JackozeeHakkiuz I'm using Mathematica for all calculations, but I don't think there are built-in functions to calculate Riemann curvature tensors and covariant derivatives. We have to write formula in Mathematica to calculate Riemann tensor and covariant derivatives.

@KurtG. I'm not trying to verify equations (1),(2), and (3). They are standard equations. But I'm trying to verify Eq. (27) using Eqs. (1) and (2). I'm using Mathematica for all calculations.

@KurtG. I have tried to write in MathJax format. I have also pasted a picture of that portion of Mathematica code. Moreover, I have also shared the Mathematica code, but it's format looked weird in the post.

I have briefly peeked into that arxiv paper and realized that that eq. (27) is truly monstrous. It seems to be of little general interest for a wider audience and I suggest that you contact the authors of that fairly recent paper.

@KurtG. Thank You!

Are you using this: https://sites.math.washington.edu/~lee/Ricci/

@Deane, Yes I am using this

I suggest doing as much of it as you can by hand.

Identities 1, 2 and 3 are very standard and they are not special for the Riemann tensor. From the previous revisions of your question I think that you are trying to calculate $\nabla^a R^i{}_{jkl}$ for the Levi-Civita connection of a specific metric. Is that right? In that case, it would be better to include the metric you are working with in your post. Otherwise there is nothing to answer here.

Thanks @JackozeeHakkiuz, yes you are right. I was trying to calculate it for the Schwarzschild spacetime. I have obtained the required results!
